# How do I list IP addresses where minions connect from?

Tags: saltstack

Some minions are behind NAT and I'd like to get their public IP address as seen from master (for firewall purposes).

There is external_ip grain but AFAIK it depends on third party service and doesn't even work reliably for me.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that each of your minion has `curl` package installed.

Then you could use:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "curl ifconfig.me"
```

If ifconfig.me doesn't respond, you can use another provider:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "curl -s icanhazip.com"
```

Each minion will respond with the external ip address:

```
zeus.example.com:
    1.2.3.1
hera.example.com:
    1.2.3.2
apollo.example.com:
    1.2.3.3
athena.example.com:
    1.2.3.4
```

If curl is not installed the response will be:

```
castor.example.com:
    /bin/bash: curl: command not found
```

Comment: They are behind a NAT. All they know is their private address...

Comment: Vasili, the command mentioned above, will return the public ip address, the one it is used to communicate with the master. Just try to run `curl ifconfig.me` from a host behind NAT, see what it returns.

Comment: But the master sees nodes' public addresses and should be able to provide them, without need to use third parties!

Comment: @Juraj, you can get the ip address of the minion via `salt '*' grains.item ipv4` but not the ip address from NAT. You query minions for information not the master itself.

Comment: @pincoded I know. 
I made feature request for that: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/15777

Answer (score 0):

A computer behind a NAT has no knowledge of the public IP address that it's meant to have... I don't think you'd be able to get this information from the minion itself.

This information has to come from your NAT device, whether it be a firewall, switch, or some other device. Maybe you could create a Runner in salt to retrieve that information for you.

Alternatively, you could simply drop in a file on your minion's filesystem that contains information such as the public IP address, which could be retrieved a bit easier...

Comment: But salt master does know where the minions connect from, why can't it publish this information?